# Filters for Gooddata "Export a large report" API

Tags: json, api, csv, filter, gooddata

I would like to know if I could filter a report before download it's data inside the csv file, I'm using this url:

```
https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/app/projects/project_id/execute/raw/
```

I couldn't found any information at [gooddata api](http://developer.gooddata.com/api#/reference/dashboards-and-reporting/export-a-large-report) about this, the body of the post request accept this json:

```
{'report_req': {'reportDefinition': '/gdc/md/{project_id}/obj/{obj_id}'} }
```

There are other parameters for filtering the data?

If don't, there is another way to download filtered data?

If there is another way, can I change from .csv to .json? Or maybe get the json data inside the response body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of filters is a part of "reportDefinition". The solution is to use or create report definition which contains required filters and perform the mentioned "execute/raw" call. Result of "execute/raw" call is always in csv format.

Comment: Yes, I tried the "Execute a report or report definition" API and worked. It still lack the json information but I think that the API doesn't provide json files as a result for "execute/raw" so far.